# Apache 2 - LDAP/eDirectory(Novell) Automatic Login / Authentication

Tags: windows, apache, authentication, ldap, novell

So I've been tasked to develop some enterprise web applications, but our users hate logging in to every site. After our users authenticate to eDirectory, is it possible to provide a Single Sign On feature for them. I know it's possible to do with AD, but I was wondering if anyone has actually done it with Novell?

Currently, I'm testing out solutions on WAMP (Apache 2.2). I was looking into mod_auth_sspi but I'm not sure if it will work with Novell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical issue on these setups is how you are going to pass credentials from the Browser to the Web Application. You can setup Kerberos on eDirectory which should work similar to Microsoft Active Directory using [GSSAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) which is vendor independent.

You may need to make some changes to browser settings to make any of these work seamlessly.

However, [SPPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface) is a proprietary variant of GSSAPI with extensions and very Windows-specific data types and AFIK, will not work easily with eDirectory or browsers other than IE.

If possible, look into a Access Manager product that will be (at least nearly) seamless. Most will allow any(?) WEB based application to utilize SSO in one form or another.
-jim